# Redirect issues with htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having a little headache with htaccess, I have the following urls:

```
www.site.com/products
www.site.com/contacts
```

They are working but I want to redirect the subdirectories that don't exist to the index page, per example:

```
 www.site.com/contacts/asdasdasd
```

to

```
 www.site.com
```

I've already a statement on .htaccess for the product details

```
 www.site.com/details/product/123



 www.site.com/(page name)/(product name)/(id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above your current rules in your .htaccess file in the root of your site, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(products|contacts)/[^/]+$ / [R=302,L]
```

This redirects any "subdirectory" of the `products` or `contacts` parent directories, that do not exist, to the document root.

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to a `301` (permanent) redirect when you are happy it's working OK. (302 redirects are not cached by the browser, so makes testing easier.)

Comment: I just forgot to add... change the `302` (temporary) redirect to a `301` (permanent) redirect when you are happy it's working OK. (302 redirects are not cached by the browser, so makes testing easier.)

Comment: you sir are a star, thanks one more time, i always struggle a lot with htaccess